# Create Custom URL structure for specific Post category

Tags: functions, urls

My Custom Structure is set to "/blog/%postname%/"

This works as expected, but for Posts with the Category "testimonials", I would like to change the URL structure to be "/testimonials/%postname%/".

I put the following code in my `functions.php`:

```
//Rewrite URLs for "testimonial" category
add_filter( 'post_link', 'custom_permalink', 10, 3 );
function custom_permalink( $permalink, $post, $leavename ) {
    // Get the category for the post
    $category = get_the_category($post->ID);
    if (  !empty($category) && $category[0]->cat_name == "Testimonials" ) {
        $cat_name = strtolower($category[0]->cat_name);
        $permalink = trailingslashit( home_url('/'. $cat_name . '/' . $post->post_name .'/' ) );
    }
    return $permalink;
}
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'custom_rewrite_rules');
function custom_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) {
    $regex = '/[\s\S]/';
    $new_rules = array(
      trailingslashit('testimonials/'.$regex) => '/?p='. get_page_by_path('$matches[1]', OBJECT, 'post')->id
    );
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
    return $wp_rewrite;
}
```

This generates the desired URL, "myurl.com/testimonials/post-name" when I try to click on the desired Post, but then it returns a 404 error.

I'd like to accomplish the URL rewrite without needing to register a new Custom Post Type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try these steps:

**Step #1:** Replace this:

```
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'custom_rewrite_rules');
function custom_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) {
    $regex = '/[\s\S]/';
    $new_rules = array(
      trailingslashit('testimonials/'.$regex) => '/?p='. get_page_by_path('$matches[1]', OBJECT, 'post')->id
    );
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
    return $wp_rewrite;
}
```

..with this one:

```
add_action( 'init', 'custom_rewrite_rules' );
function custom_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'testimonials/([^/]+)(?:/([0-9]+))?/?$',
        'index.php?category_name=testimonials&name=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]',
        'top' // The rule position; either 'top' or 'bottom' (default).
    );
}
```

**Step #2:** Go to the *Permalink Settings* page, and click on the *Save Changes* button without actually making any changes.

Comment: This was perfect, thanks. Can you point me toward any resources or tips on how to do the same for the Category page? Currently the category page shows as /blog/category/testimonials/, and I would like to change it to just /testimonials/

I tried the plugin here https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/, which works, but then breaks your above solution for individual posts and returns a 404

Comment: You're welcome! And as for the Category page, take a look at my [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/296703/137402), which I wrote in a similar style/format to the one for this question.

Comment: This works great, but is there a way to not affect subfolder pages with the same category name?  My use case is to create a subfolder section of the website, so all posts with the category "learn" have website.com/learn.  
I also have pages that us the same subfolder name,  website.com/learn/page.  The above code works perfectly for posts, but I get a 404 for pages.  If I change the rule position to "bottom", the code works for pages, but then I get a 404 for posts.  Is there a way to have the rewrite rule only affect posts?

Comment: @agentcurry, I'd love to help, but I suggest you to post that as a new question. :)

Comment: Thanks, @SallyCJ, will do!