# Give specific category its own permalink structure

Tags: categories

For the purposes of my site, I have my Permalinks set to `/blog/%postname%/` for all posts.

However, I need to give Posts with a specific Category (in this case, "Testimonials") its own permalink structure, where each individual post assigned the Category "Testimonials" returns as `/testimonials/%postname%/` and the Category Archive page returns as `/testimonials/`.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
//Rewrite URLs for "testimonial" category
add_filter( 'post_link', 'custom_permalink', 10, 3 );
function custom_permalink( $permalink, $post, $leavename ) {
    // Get the category for the post
    $category = get_the_category($post->ID);
    if (  !empty($category) && $category[0]->cat_name == "Testimonials" ) {
        $cat_name = strtolower($category[0]->cat_name);
        $permalink = trailingslashit( home_url('/'. $cat_name . '/' . $post->post_name .'/' ) );
    }
    return $permalink;
}

add_action( 'init', 'custom_rewrite_rules' );
function custom_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'testimonials/([^/]+)(?:/([0-9]+))?/?$',
        'index.php?category_name=testimonials&name=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]',
        'top' // The rule position; either 'top' or 'bottom' (default).
    );
}
```

This successfully returns each individual post with the category "Testimonials" as `/testimonials/%postname%/`. However, the Category Archive page returns as `/blog/category/testimonials`. I need this to just return as `/testimonials/`, while still returning all other Posts as `/blog/%postname%/`

I tried using this plugin, https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/, which solved the Category Archive page issue, but broke each individual testimonial post, returning them as a 404 error.

In this case, I cannot register Testimonials as a Custom Post Type as it will affect other site functionality,

Comment: Is there a reason you don't have the testimonials set as a custom post type?

Comment: The site was inherited from a previous developer. I'd like to know if I can solve this issue by rewriting the URL structure, as opposed to registering a custom post type and porting every single Post with that category over to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try these steps:

**Step #1:** Replace this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'custom_rewrite_rules' );
function custom_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'testimonials/([^/]+)(?:/([0-9]+))?/?$',
        'index.php?category_name=testimonials&name=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]',
        'top' // The rule position; either 'top' or 'bottom' (default).
    );
}
```

..with this one:

```
add_filter( 'category_link', 'custom_category_permalink', 10, 2 );
function custom_category_permalink( $link, $cat_id ) {
    $slug = get_term_field( 'slug', $cat_id, 'category' );
    if ( ! is_wp_error( $slug ) && 'testimonials' === $slug ) {
        $link = home_url( user_trailingslashit( '/testimonials/', 'category' ) );
    }
    return $link;
}

add_action( 'init', 'custom_rewrite_rules' );
function custom_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'testimonials(?:/page/?([0-9]{1,})|)/?$',
        'index.php?category_name=testimonials&paged=$matches[1]',
        'top' // The rule position; either 'top' or 'bottom' (default).
    );

    add_rewrite_rule(
        'testimonials/([^/]+)(?:/([0-9]+))?/?$',
        'index.php?category_name=testimonials&name=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]',
        'top' // The rule position; either 'top' or 'bottom' (default).
    );
}
```

**Step #2:** Go to the *Permalink Settings* page, and click on the *Save Changes* button without actually making any changes.

Comment: This worked, thank you very much. Encouraging to know that thinking to add another "add_rewrite_rule" function was on the right track, but I had not known about the "category_link" filter. Thanks again!

Comment: You're very welcome. =)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add the post id then? If that's all you need? You could just do this with `query_vars`

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'my_query_vars' );
```

You only need to check if you are in the 'special' category and if yes, add the var. Then utilizing the `pre_get_posts` hook, check if your post contains an ID and if yes change your query to get desired post.

Comment: without adding actual rewrite rules wordpress will not know how to parse the url. There is no way to go around it