# Giving specific category posts its own permalink structure returns 404

Tags: permalinks, urls, 404-error

i am trying to give a specific category posts it's own permalink. Followed the steps from this topic ([Give specific category its own permalink structure](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/296699/give-specific-category-its-own-permalink-structure/296703#296703)) but the posts are giving a 404 error.

Cleared cache, saved permalinks under settings but to no avail.

Would appreciate help in fixing this.

Thanks

here is my code:

```
//Rewrite URLs for "testimonial" category
add_filter( 'post_link', 'custom_permalink', 10, 3 );
function custom_permalink( $permalink, $post, $leavename ) {
    // Get the category for the post
    $category = get_the_category($post->ID);
    if (  !empty($category) && $category[0]->cat_name == "Foodguide" ) {
        $cat_name = strtolower($category[0]->cat_name);
        $permalink = trailingslashit( home_url('/'. $cat_name . '/' . $post->ID . '/' . $post->post_name .'/' ) );
    }
    return $permalink;
}

add_filter( 'category_link', 'custom_category_permalink', 10, 2 );
function custom_category_permalink( $link, $cat_id ) {
    $slug = get_term_field( 'slug', $cat_id, 'category' );
    if ( ! is_wp_error( $slug ) && 'foodguide' === $slug ) {
        $link = home_url( user_trailingslashit( '/foodguide/', 'category' ) );
    }
    return $link;
}

add_action( 'init', 'custom_rewrite_rules' );
function custom_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'foodguide(?:/page/?([0-9]{1,})|)/?$',
        'index.php?category_name=foodguide&paged=$matches[1]',
        'top' // The rule position; either 'top' or 'bottom' (default).
    );

    add_rewrite_rule(
        'foodguide/([^/]+)(?:/([0-9]+))?/?$',
        'index.php?category_name=foodguide&name=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]',
        'top' // The rule position; either 'top' or 'bottom' (default).
    );
}
```

Comment: Post *your* code.

Comment: Updated the post with the code.

Comment: The post permalink includes the post ID (e.g. `example.com/foodguide/1/hello-world`), but your rewrite rules doesn't include the pattern for that post ID. So remove the `'/' . $post->ID .` (in your `custom_permalink` function). Otherwise, you need to change the rewrite rules/regex.

Comment: Can you help me out with the correct regex pls?

Comment: Yes, but I'm sorry for the delay.. quite busy lately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, the [`add_rewrite_rule()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/) syntax is `add_rewrite_rule( 'RegEx pattern', 'WordPress query string/vars', 'position/priority - top or bottom' )`.

Now I could see you're trying to have the following permalink structure:

```
Structure: example.com/foodguide/<post ID>/<post slug>
Example:   example.com/foodguide/1/sample-food-guide
```

But your rewrite rule (the second one in your code) does not have the proper RegEx [subpattern](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php) for the post ID part in the permalink; hence, the permalink leads to a `404` error page.

And to fix the issue, you can add `\d+/` to the rewrite rule:

```php
add_rewrite_rule(
    'foodguide/\d+/([^/]+)(?:/([0-9]+))?/?$', // <- here, add the \d+/
    'index.php?category_name=foodguide&name=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]',
    'top'
);
```

Alternatively, in the RegEx pattern, you can "capture" the post ID (i.e. use `(\d+)`) and not the post slug, and then in the WordPress query, use the `p` (i.e. ID) parameter instead of `name` (i.e. slug):

```php
add_rewrite_rule(
    'foodguide/(\d+)/[^/]+(?:/([0-9]+))?/?$', // capture the \d+
    // $matches[1] is now the post ID, so use &p= instead of &name=
    'index.php?category_name=foodguide&p=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]',
    'top'
);
```

PS: Don't forget to flush the rewrite rules — just visit the permalink settings page.

### UPDATE

If you want the post permalink to end with a `.html`, then:

1. In `custom_permalink()`, make the following change:

   ```php
   // Change this:
   $permalink = trailingslashit( home_url('/'. $cat_name . '/' . $post->ID . '/' . $post->post_name .'/' ) );

   // To this:
   $permalink = untrailingslashit( home_url( '/'. $cat_name . '/' . $post->ID . '/' . $post->post_name . '.html' ) );
   ```
2. In `custom_rewrite_rules()`, change the second `add_rewrite_rule()` to this:

   ```php
   add_rewrite_rule(
       '^foodguide/(\d+)/[^/]+\.html$',
       'index.php?category_name=foodguide&p=$matches[1]',
       'top'
   );
   ```
3. After the `function custom_rewrite_rules() { ... }`, add this:

   ```php
   function cancel_canonical_redirect( $wp ) {
       if ( '^foodguide/(\d+)/[^/]+\.html$' === $wp->matched_rule ) {
           remove_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical' );
       }
   }
   add_action( 'parse_request', 'cancel_canonical_redirect' );
   ```

   That would prevent "adding" the ending slash (`/`) to the permalink URL.

And once again, don't forget to flush the permalinks.

Also, I've not added support for *paginated requests* (i.e. posts having the `<!--nextpage-->` tag or the Page Break block in Gutenberg); and if you need that, let me know.

### UPDATE 2

For paginated requests with this permalink/URL structure:

```
example.com/foodguide/<post ID>/<post slug>/page-<page number>.html
```

1. In `custom_rewrite_rules()`, change the second `add_rewrite_rule()` to this:

   ```php
   add_rewrite_rule(
       '^foodguide/(\d+)/[^/]+(?:/page-(\d+)|)\.html$',
       'index.php?category_name=foodguide&p=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]',
       'top'
   );
   ```
2. Change the `cancel_canonical_redirect` to (* the RegEx pattern needs to match the one used in the above `add_rewrite_rule()`):

   ```php
   function cancel_canonical_redirect( $wp ) {
       if ( '^foodguide/(\d+)/[^/]+(?:/page-(\d+)|)\.html$' === $wp->matched_rule ) {
           remove_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical' );
       }
   }
   add_action( 'parse_request', 'cancel_canonical_redirect' );
   ```
3. After the above code, add this:

   ```php
   function custom_wp_link_pages_link( $link, $i ) {
       if ( in_category( 'foodguide' ) ) {
           $name = get_post_field( 'post_name' );
           $link = str_replace(
               "{$name}.html/$i/",     // replace example.com/foodguide/<post ID>/<post slug>.html/<page number>/
               "$name/page-{$i}.html", // with example.com/foodguide/<post ID>/<post slug>/page-<page number>.html
               $link
           );
       }
       return $link;
   }
   add_filter( 'wp_link_pages_link', 'custom_wp_link_pages_link', 10, 2 );
   ```

And as always, be sure to flush the permalinks.

Comment: Thank you so much. This works great. 

If i want to keep this structure, what change should i be making?

Structure: example.com/foodguide/<post ID>/<post slug>.html
Example:   example.com/foodguide/1/sample-food-guide.html

Comment: I already answered the original question, so could you please accept the answer? But don't worry, I'll update the answer with the new structure you need (when I get back to my computer).

Comment: Hi.
yes, i  have accepted the answer already :)

Comment: Thanks. :) Check the "UPDATE" part and let me know.

Comment: Thank you so much.
As of now, none of the posts are paginated and i don't use Gutenberg. But just in case if it becomes an issue later, can you please share the support code also?

Comment: How would you like the structure be for paginated requests? Is it `example.com/foodguide/<post ID>/<page number>/<post slug>.html` ?

Comment: Can it be example.com/foodguide/<post ID>/<post slug>/page-<page number>.html

Comment: Yes, sure can. Check the "UPDATE 2" part.

Comment: Hi.
Have an issue.
I set this up on a demo server and it worked fine. However on the live site, it keeps throwing random errors.
1. The post that i click does not load and it goes to a random post.
2. The url part shows up fine on mouseover, but when clicked it does not go to /foodguide/.... 
It goes to /defaulturl/...
3. The page isn’t redirecting properly error shows up

I saved the permalinks multiple times, flushed permalinks cache but nothing seemed to work.

Can u help?

Comment: Sorry, but I already answered more than what was originally asked in the question. If you need further assistance, you can post another question - but no promises that I can help. After all, those issues could happen because of various reasons like plugins or theme conflict. What I can suggest is try deactivating all plugins and switch to a default theme; if none helps, then maybe something's not quite right in the server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the code from functions.php. Instead of that do the following,

Step 1:Go to the settings -> permalink in the WordPress dashboard(Refer to this link).
[image]

Step 2:Select the **Custom Structure** in the permalink settings page(Refer to this link).
[image]

Step 3:Change the Permalink to our requirement and click the save changes button(Refer this link).
[image]

Step 4:Then the permalink of the post is changed as we given in the settings page(Refer this link).
[image]

Comment: Hi
This is not the answer i was after. 

What i am looking for is to rewrite the url structure for one particular category posts alone and not for the entire site.